# How to reference schema 1 or shema 2 in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

How to tell Shema 3 is array item to reference Schema 1 or 2 ?

```
const model3Schema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    items: [
        {
        model: { type: String },
        modelId: {
          type: ObjectId,
          required: true,
          ref: 'model1' // or   ref: 'model2'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding your question, I not sure this is possible without combining the documents of schema 1 and 2 into one collection (i.e. to have only one schema to reference).

Comment: @codemonkey if i can not do that then what is the `refPath`
there is a Dynamic references via `refPath`  here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref 
I tried to do that with refPath I'm only able to save Ids but I don't know how to populate an array with two different schemas.